# NgModules not working with NgUpgrade

Tags: angular, ng-upgrade

Angular 1 & 2 (RC5) application running in hybrid mode using ng-upgrade.
Attempt to use `@NgModule` which doesn't work, I still have to add providers manually using:

```
 upgradeAdapter.addProvider(REACTIVE_FORM_PROVIDERS);
```

This is preventing me from upgrading from RC5->RC6.
To use external components, I still have to add them to the directives: array for the specific component they're being used in.

```
import { AlertComponent } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'sb-staff-dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'staff-dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['staff-dashboard.component.scss'],
    directives: [ AlertComponent ]
})
```

Here is my relevant bootstrap code.

```
upgradeAdapter.addProvider(COMMON_PROVIDERS);
upgradeAdapter.addProvider(HTTP_PROVIDERS);
upgradeAdapter.addProvider(DragulaService);
upgradeAdapter.addProvider(REACTIVE_FORM_PROVIDERS);
upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['common', CommonModule], { strictDi: true });
```

upgradeAdapter.ts

```
import {UpgradeAdapter} from '@angular/upgrade';

export const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
```

common.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Ng2BootstrapModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { Dragula, DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        Ng2BootstrapModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        COMMON_COMPONENTS,
        Dragula
    ],
    providers: [
        COMMON_PROVIDERS,
        DragulaService
    ]
})
export class CommonModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the `UpgradeAdapter` with the module you want.

For example:

```
import { forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UpgradeAdapter } from '@angular/upgrade';

export const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter(forwardRef(() => CommonModule));
```

Also, instead of importing `COMMON_COMPONENTS` and `COMMON_PROVIDERS` you have to use:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({imports: [CommonModule, ...]})
```

Comment: Note, the `forwardRef` is imported from @angular/core